# Vim: SnipMate + HAML

Tags: vim, autocomplete, haml, snipmate

I've recently configured SnipMate to work alongside autocomplete for Rails development. I've bound both SnipMate and autocomplete to Tab, which works beautifully.

However, when dealing with Haml files, Tab isn't behaving as expected. Instead of inserting tabs (when no autocomplete or snippet is available), it's moving my cursor to the next blank line in the document.

Disabling SnipMate resolves the issue, but then I have no SnipMate.

Does anyone know where I might look to fix this?

Cheers,
-W

Answer (score 0):

Use ctrl+tab to disable SnipMate tab behavior

Answer (score 0):

install the supertab plugin and config it to use both.